# How many permutations (bijections) are there on the set B = {0,1}^(8) of bytes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many permutations (bijections) are there on the set B = {0,1}^(8) of bytes?

Prove that this set forms a group under the composition operation: g • f is defined by (g •  f)(x) = g(f(x)).